# Java try-catch-finally scopes, determining if the variable is used

Tags: java, scope, try-catch

I have the following code:

```
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String records = "";
        System.out.println("EMITTER QUEUE BACKUP: restoring from file...");
        try {
            while(reader.ready()) {
                records += reader.readLine();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("EMITTER QUEUE BACKUP: error restoring");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        doSomethingWith(records);
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The `records` variable in the `doSomethingWith(records);` line causes an error as undefined. This is ok, I can understand that its definition in the first `try` block sometimes may not occure. But there is the question: if I delete the `doSomethingWith(records);` line then the `records` variable in the first `try` block is marked as unused!!! So why does it recognize it as used in that line even if it causes an apparent mistake because it is assumed that it is not the same variable and thus it can't stand for a usage case of the `String records = ""`?

If that matters, my IDE is Eclipse.

Comment: No, your IDE doesn't matter at all for the language you're writing :-)

Comment: I pasted the code into my eclipse and the `records` variable is unused no matter if I remove `doSomethingWith(records);` or not. It's different var. You have class property `records`, true?

Comment: Hmm, nope, no such class property I have. This piece of code is literally all that this class has (e.g. except for the declaration of the reader)

Comment: @PeterGwiazda You may have different compiler error / warning settings set. I get the same as the OP with my settings in eclipse.

Comment: This shouldn't compile. Here `doSomethingWith(records);` variable `records` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not just that the definition may not occur, the variable declaration is outside the scope of the finally block.  If that's declared outside the try it will stop the error.

As to why eclipse doesn't state that it's unused when the error is present, my guess is that the error is obscuring the warning?  It never gets to the warning stage as the error occurs first in the compilation process?

Comment: True, just now I have concluded the experement where I have declared a second intentionally unused variable in the same place, and yes, the error obscured it. Never noticed this kind of behavior before.. but anyway, it is good to know!

Answer (score 1):

`{` and `}` decide the scope for a construct in Java.

`records` variable scope is limited to the end brace to `try` construct and you are trying to use it outside, i.e. within `finally` block. and that's why you are getting error.

> line causes an error as undefined. This is ok, I can understand that its definition in the first try block sometimes may not occure.

Actually that's not the reason. but it's realated to the scope of variable.

> if I delete the doSomethingWith(records); line then the records variable in the first try block is marked as unused!!!

Assigning a variable is not considered by Java that it is being used.

And error is preferred over warning.

Answer (score 0):

`records` is assigned inside "try" block but is never read. Assigning a variable without reading the result is useless.

Comment: Nevermind, I have misread the question. Couldn't redact the vote without editing, though :/

Answer (score -1):

You can initialize records before the start of try i suppose because as it is you are making it an empty string. ""